# Using contexts in React with Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-context

I can't get my Context working in a React/Gatsby project.

It's quite simple, I must be missing something.

I have a parent component which creates the context and renders two children in the context provider. The two children consume the context.

When I run this code, the user values do not change and seem to always be the default values. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

The parent component is:

```
// parent

import React, { useEffect, useState, createContext } from 'react'
import type { PageProps } from 'gatsby'

import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar2'
import Main from '../../components/Main2'


export type Nullable<T> = T | null

export interface User {
  name: string
  email: string
}


const loadingTime = 1.5       // s

const loadUser = (): Promise<User> => {
  return new Promise<User>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({
        name: "Jeff",
        email: 'jeff@example.com',
      })
    }, loadingTime*1000)
  })
}


export interface UserState {
  user: Nullable<User>
  isLoading: boolean
  isLoaded: boolean
}

export const UserContext = createContext<UserState>({
  user: null,
  isLoading: true,
  isLoaded: false,
})


const Page: React.FC<PageProps> = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<Nullable<User>>(null)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect')
    setIsLoading(true)
    loadUser()
      .then(user => {
        console.log('then')
        setUser(user)
        setIsLoaded(true)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('catch')
        setUser(null)
        setIsLoaded(false)
      })
      .finally(() => {
        console.log('finally')
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{
      user: user,
      isLoading: isLoading,
      isLoaded: isLoaded,
    }}>
      <Navbar />
      <Main />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}


export default Page
```

and the two children

```
// Navbar2.tsx

import React, { useContext } from 'react'

import { UserContext, UserState } from '../pages/tests/user2'


interface Props {}


const Navbar: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const { user, isLoading, isLoaded } = useContext<UserState>(UserContext)

  return (
    <div style={{borderBottom: '1px solid gray'}}>
      Email: {isLoaded ? user?.email : (isLoading ? "..." : "No user")}
    </div>
  )
}


export default Navbar
```

and

```
// Main2.tsx

import React, { useContext } from 'react'

import { UserContext, UserState } from '../pages/tests/user2'


const Main = () => {
  const userContext = useContext<UserState>(UserContext)

  console.log('Main', userContext)

  return (
    <div>
      {userContext.isLoaded ? (
        <h1>
          Welcome {userContext.user?.name}
        </h1>
      ) : (userContext.isLoading ? (
        '...'
      ) : (
        "No user loaded"
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}


export default Main
```

Any help would be welcome :-)

Comment: Looks ok at first glance but you don't need the generic arg for `useContext` because the context passed determines the return type. You can simply use `useContext(UserContext)`

Comment: I can not reproduce any such problem ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-gianmarco-sry9v9?file=/src/Page.tsx

Comment: Thanks a lot Phil. I will investigate further, but this may be a Gatsby or react version issue...

Comment: Hmm.. I had faced a similar problem before when I was new to frontend, I didn't saved the file. Did you save all the files ... ?

Comment: As for the generic arg, I get an error without it "Type 'Nullable<User>' is not assignable to type 'null'".

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for providing a [mcve] including mock service definitions. That makes it so much easier to diagnose (even though there's no apparent problem with this one)

Comment: Sorry Phil, you were right about the generic arg. I read your comment too fast, thought you said it was not needed at the `createContext` level.

Comment: You might be experiencing an issue due to the circular dependencies. Try refactoring so that your Navbar file isn't importing from the Page file, possibly by either extracting the UserContext provider into another file and passing children to it as props, or by extracting at least the `UserContext` definition to its own file that both Page and Navbar import from.

Comment: As mentioned by Phil, the code actually works on codesandbox. The difference between the sandbox and my code is that I use Gatsby, and possibly another version of React. I don't expect imports behave differently, but I'll give it a go anyway and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is valid React code.

It works as expected here https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-gianmarco-sry9v9?file=/src/Page.tsx and I could also try it in another React framework and it works (https://nextjs.org).

**This is actually a Gatsby issue.**

It looks like this one: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/25616

I did not try to fix it, as using a React framework that does not accept basic valid  React code seems unwise. I instead decided investigating using another framework.